# Save state with either Cookie or Session Storage in jQuery / JS / HTML /CSS

Tags: jquery, cookies, state, session-storage, jquery-cookie

I am trying to save the state of a popup which is getting an "active" Class on document.ready. On close the state should be saved to a cookie or to sessionstorage for a certain time, so that on browser refresh the popup still has its last / most recent state. No need to toggle though as there is no possibility of reactivating once it is closed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   /* Initial State */

   $('#popup').addClass("active")

   /* Close and set new state */

   $('.close').click(function () {
     $('#item').removeClass("active");
     $('#item2').removeClass("anotherclass");
     $('#item4').removeClass("moreclasses");

     /* Set Cookie for 12 hrs containing the state or use sessionStorage 
      with exp. time of 12hrs if that is possible. */
   }); 
});
```

I would like to save the state whether the user closed the item by clicking on .close in either a cookie or in a session storage.

Goal: Save state of the popup and do not show it within a certain period of time (12hrs) I was thinking about using cookies as I feel like they are easier to handle concerning their expiration date?

Could anyone help me out with this?
Here is a slightly more specific [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Papawhoop/5h6rz677/)